# Can't find Boost using Visual Studio 2019 and GitHub actions

Tags: visual-studio, boost, cmake, github-actions

Trying to install Boost as static library, so I can include it in my binary to not need to install it on system. But it seems to failed of this error below:

```
Run cmake . -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -B build -DSTATIC=true
-DDO_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fassociative-math" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fassociative-math" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0   
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30147.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30147.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
- skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
- skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE   CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:43 (set):   implicitly converting 'TYPE' to 'STRING' type.
-- FORCE_USE_HEAP: ENABLED This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
-- HW AES: ENABLED
-- OPTIMIZED_ARM_MULTIPLICATION: ENABLED

-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):   Could NOT find Boost (missing: system filesystem thread date_time chrono   regex serialization program_options) (found version "1.74.0") Call Stack (most recent call first):   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)   CMakeLists.txt:270 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "D:/a/kryptokrona/kryptokrona/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "D:/a/kryptokrona/kryptokrona/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

So this is how I set it up in CMake:

```
# Go get us some static BOOST libraries
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

# Checker if we build on GitHub Actions and building for Visual C++
if(DEFINED ENV{CI} AND MSVC)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
    set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
else()
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON) # ON was before
endif()
```

In GitHub workflow:

```
# install dependencies
  - name: Install Windows 2019 Dependencies
    if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-2019'
    uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1
    with:
      msbuild-architecture: x64

  - name: Install Windows Boost
    if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-2019'
    run: |
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.74.0/source/boost_1_74_0.zip -OutFile C:\boost_1_74_0.zip
      Expand-Archive C:\boost_1_74_0.zip -DestinationPath C:\boost_1_74_0
      Set-Location C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0\tools\build
      C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0\tools\build\bootstrap.bat
      .\b2 toolset=msvc variant=release optimization=space threading=multi link=static address-model=64 install

- name: Build Windows 2019
  if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-2019'
  run: |
          cmake . -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -B build -DSTATIC=true -DDO_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fassociative-math" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fassociative-math" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0
          cmake --build ./build --config Release
```

How can I make this work to load Boost so it loads Boosts? It works on macOS and Ubuntu since I install them system wide first. But then compile it as static.

After passing debug options on for Boost this is the output:

```
- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1689 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.80.0;1.80;1.79.0;1.79;1.78.0;1.78;1.77.0;1.77;1.76.0;1.76;1.75.0;1.75;1.74.0;1.74;1.73.0;1.73;1.72.0;1.72;1.71.0;1.71;1.70.0;1.70;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1690 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "ON"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1691 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "ON"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1692 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = "ON"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1693 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1694 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = "ON"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1726 ] BOOST_ROOT = "C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1727 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1728 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1729 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1730 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1731 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1803 ] _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = "C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/include;C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0;NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH;NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1804 ] _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = "boost-1_80_0;boost_1_80_0;boost/boost-1_80_0;boost/boost_1_80_0;boost-1_80;boost_1_80;boost/boost-1_80;boost/boost_1_80;boost-1_79_0;boost_1_79_0;boost/boost-1_79_0;boost/boost_1_79_0;boost-1_79;boost_1_79;boost/boost-1_79;boost/boost_1_79;boost-1_78_0;boost_1_78_0;boost/boost-1_78_0;boost/boost_1_78_0;boost-1_78;boost_1_78;boost/boost-1_78;boost/boost_1_78;boost-1_77_0;boost_1_77_0;boost/boost-1_77_0;boost/boost_1_77_0;boost-1_77;boost_1_77;boost/boost-1_77;boost/boost_1_77;boost-1_76_0;boost_1_76_0;boost/boost-1_76_0;boost/boost_1_76_0;boost-1_76;boost_1_76;boost/boost-1_76;boost/boost_1_76;boost-1_75_0;boost_1_75_0;boost/boost-1_75_0;boost/boost_1_75_0;boost-1_75;boost_1_75;boost/boost-1_75;boost/boost_1_75;boost-1_74_0;boost_1_74_0;boost/boost-1_74_0;boost/boost_1_74_0;boost-1_74;boost_1_74;boost/boost-1_74;boost/boost_1_74;boost-1_73_0;boost_1_73_0;boost/boost-1_73_0;boost/boost_1_73_0;boost-1_73;boost_1_7...
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1819 ] location of version.hpp: C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1859 ] Boost_VERSION = "107400"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1860 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.74.0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1861 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107400"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1862 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1863 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "74"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1864 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1865 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1889 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = "lib"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1890 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-vc142;-vc141;-vc140" (guessed)
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1926 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2004 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "-x64" (detected)
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2008 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-s"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2009 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-sgd"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2069 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/lib;C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/stage/lib;C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/lib;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/../lib;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/../lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/../lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/../lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH;NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2070 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/lib;C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/stage/lib;C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/lib;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/../lib;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/../lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/../lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/../lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost_1_74_0/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH;NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_system-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_system-vc142-mt-s-x64;libboost_system-vc142-mt-s;libboost_system-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_system-vc141-mt-s-x64;libboost_system-vc141-mt-s;libboost_system-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_system-vc140-mt-s-x64;libboost_system-vc140-mt-s;libboost_system-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_system-mt-s-x64;libboost_system-mt-s;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_system-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_system-vc142-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_system-vc142-mt-sgd;libboost_system-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_system-vc141-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_system-vc141-mt-sgd;libboost_system-vc140-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_system-vc140-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_system-vc140-mt-sgd;libboost_system-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_system-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_system-mt-sgd;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-s-x64;libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-s;libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-s-x64;libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-s;libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-s-x64;libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-s;libboost_filesystem-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mt-s-x64;libboost_filesystem-mt-s;libboost_filesystem-mt;libboost_filesystem
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-sgd;libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-sgd;libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-sgd;libboost_filesystem-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_filesystem-mt-sgd;libboost_filesystem-mt;libboost_filesystem
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_thread-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_thread-vc142-mt-s-x64;libboost_thread-vc142-mt-s;libboost_thread-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_thread-vc141-mt-s-x64;libboost_thread-vc141-mt-s;libboost_thread-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_thread-vc140-mt-s-x64;libboost_thread-vc140-mt-s;libboost_thread-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_thread-mt-s-x64;libboost_thread-mt-s;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_thread-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_thread-vc142-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_thread-vc142-mt-sgd;libboost_thread-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_thread-vc141-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_thread-vc141-mt-sgd;libboost_thread-vc140-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_thread-vc140-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_thread-vc140-mt-sgd;libboost_thread-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_thread-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_thread-mt-sgd;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-s-x64;libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-s;libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-s-x64;libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-s;libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-s-x64;libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-s;libboost_date_time-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_date_time-mt-s-x64;libboost_date_time-mt-s;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-sgd;libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-sgd;libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-sgd;libboost_date_time-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_date_time-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_date_time-mt-sgd;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-s-x64;libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-s;libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-s-x64;libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-s;libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-s-x64;libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-s;libboost_chrono-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_chrono-mt-s-x64;libboost_chrono-mt-s;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-sgd;libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-sgd;libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-sgd;libboost_chrono-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_chrono-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_chrono-mt-sgd;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_regex-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_regex-vc142-mt-s-x64;libboost_regex-vc142-mt-s;libboost_regex-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_regex-vc141-mt-s-x64;libboost_regex-vc141-mt-s;libboost_regex-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_regex-vc140-mt-s-x64;libboost_regex-vc140-mt-s;libboost_regex-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_regex-mt-s-x64;libboost_regex-mt-s;libboost_regex-mt;libboost_regex
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_regex-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_regex-vc142-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_regex-vc142-mt-sgd;libboost_regex-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_regex-vc141-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_regex-vc141-mt-sgd;libboost_regex-vc140-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_regex-vc140-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_regex-vc140-mt-sgd;libboost_regex-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_regex-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_regex-mt-sgd;libboost_regex-mt;libboost_regex
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-s-x64;libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-s;libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-s-x64;libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-s;libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-s-x64;libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-s;libboost_serialization-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_serialization-mt-s-x64;libboost_serialization-mt-s;libboost_serialization-mt;libboost_serialization
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-sgd;libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-sgd;libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-sgd;libboost_serialization-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_serialization-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_serialization-mt-sgd;libboost_serialization-mt;libboost_serialization
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-s-x64;libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-s;libboost_program_options-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_program_options-vc141-mt-s-x64;libboost_program_options-vc141-mt-s;libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-s-x64;libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-s;libboost_program_options-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_program_options-mt-s-x64;libboost_program_options-mt-s;libboost_program_options-mt;libboost_program_options
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-sgd;libboost_program_options-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_program_options-vc141-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_program_options-vc141-mt-sgd;libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-sgd;libboost_program_options-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_program_options-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_program_options-mt-sgd;libboost_program_options-mt;libboost_program_options
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_atomic-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_atomic-vc142-mt-s-x64;libboost_atomic-vc142-mt-s;libboost_atomic-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_atomic-vc141-mt-s-x64;libboost_atomic-vc141-mt-s;libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-s-x64;libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-s;libboost_atomic-mt-s-x64-1_74;libboost_atomic-mt-s-x64;libboost_atomic-mt-s;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_atomic-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_atomic-vc142-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_atomic-vc142-mt-sgd;libboost_atomic-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_atomic-vc141-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_atomic-vc141-mt-sgd;libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-sgd;libboost_atomic-mt-sgd-x64-1_74;libboost_atomic-mt-sgd-x64;libboost_atomic-mt-sgd;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: system filesystem thread date_time chrono
  regex serialization program_options) (found version "1.74.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
See also "D:/a/kryptokrona/kryptokrona/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  CMakeLists.txt:270 (find_package)
See also "D:/a/kryptokrona/kryptokrona/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Pass additional option `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` to `cmake`. That way CMake will print exact names of Boost libraries which are searched and exact directories where they are searched. Compare these libraries names and directories with ones you actually have after installation of the Boost.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Added the debug options now and the output of it.

Comment: The line with `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG` lists directories where Boost libraries are searched. Do you have libraries (with `.lib` extension) in any of these directories? In which one? The line `SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG` describes names of the library file (without extension) which is searched for the `system` component. Since searching fails, none of those libraries exists on your machine. But what is the **exact name** of the library file for `system` component on your machine?

Comment: It seems it does not get created when using `link=static` instead of `link=shared`. As I understand when using static these files will get compiled in my application together to create a target and not load from external libs? Or have I misunderstood static/shared libraries with Boost?

Comment: "As I understand when using static these files will get compiled in my application together to create a target and not load from external libs?" - Yes, this is true. But for "compile these files into your application" those files needs to **exist** when your application is built. `link=static` should actually create **static libraries**: https://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/tutorial/linkage.html