# Could NOT find Boost while building avro

Tags: boost, cmake, avro

while building Avro 1.11.1 on CMake  on windows giving error

```
CMake Error at D:/fesapiEnv/depenedencies/cmake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: iostreams program_options regex system)
  (found suitable version "1.73.0", minimum required is "1.38")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/fesapiEnv/depenedencies/cmake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  D:/fesapiEnv/depenedencies/cmake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:78 (find_package)
```

when we run command on **cmake -G "Visual Studio 16"** it gives error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGPYT.png)

On Windows

tried with Cmake

tried with CLI >cmake -G "Visual Studio 16"

Comment: The first line (before "CMake error") on the screenshot resembles **Boost debug output** (with `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` option). Show (add to the question post) full this output. (You could find example of such output in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74590452/3440745). Boost debug output contains **exact paths**, where Boost libraries are searched, and **exact names of library files**, which are searched. Compare these files and library names with the ones you **actually have**.

Comment: Oh, it's another cannot find boost question. https://i.imgflip.com/3x3lfs.png?a463704. (welcome to SO, by the way!)

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.